# I don't understand how value is changing between next and prev in the program?

Tags: c++

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
     {
      int prev=-1;
      int next=1;
      int n;
      cin>>n;
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
          cout<<prev+next<<endl;
          next=prev+next-next+(prev=next);//assigning prev and next
       }
      }
```

I can not understand assigning prev and next.In second line between for loop how operator precedence works?

Comment: Simple answer: Don't even try.  Code should be clear and this is the opposite of clear.  Throw it away and find better code to look at.

Comment: Behaviour of your program is not strictly defined. `prev` and `prev=next` can be evaluated in any order.

Comment: This: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` combined with `using namespace std;` can shoot you in the head countless different ways. The first says, "Include the entire C++ standard library in my file." The second says, "Put the standard library into the global namespace." Now you have the entire standard library in the global namespace. That's a lot of function, class, and variable names you now have to watch out for. You could find yourself sharing a name like `reverse`, `swap`, `find`, `max`, `min`, `copy` to comedic effect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Include headers you need as per specification.

Second, your example has undefined behavior in it - you are modifying and reading the same value before reaching sequence point.

Comment: Each value is modified only once. The problem is that the value of `prev` is both modified and read, and the two operations are not sequenced.

Comment: @RaymondChen, true. Let me edit.